# styled-components v4 syntax on animation css

Tags: jquery, reactjs, next.js, styled-components

I recently upgraded my styled-components from v3 to v4. 
The below css ${jquery} animation line would work on v3 but cannot seem to get it working on v4.

```
const StyledGlide = styled(Glide)`
    animation: ${ifProp("isOpen", `0.8s ${slideInRightAnimation}`, `0.9s ${fadeOutLeftAnimation} forwards`)};
`
```

I get this error:
*It seems you are interpolating a keyframe declaration (ifGrPa) into an untagged string. This was supported in styled-components v3, but is no longer supported in v4 as keyframes are now injected on-demand. Please wrap your string in the css`` helper which ensures the styles are injected correctly. See https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#css*

I tried changing the syntax but can't seem to get it right.

```
const StyledGlide = styled(Glide)`
    animation: ${ifProp("isOpen", css\`0.8s ${slideInRightAnimation}`, `0.9s ${fadeOutLeftAnimation} forwards\`)};
`
```

Comment: can you show `ifProp` ?

Comment: ```isOpen: PropTypes.bool```

Comment: ${ifProp("isOpen", css\`0.8s ${slideInRightAnimation}\`, css\`0.9s ${fadeOutLeftAnimation} forwards\`)}... if you try this like this, what happens? I meant show definition of `ifProp` (seems to be a function)

Comment: I am facing same issue with `const animationStyles = {
  animation: css`
    ${fadeIn} 0.5s
  `,
};` . Can you please me to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so this fixed the issue. Thanks Delis there was just an animation: missing from your statements.

`import styled, { css } from "styled-components"`

```
const StyledGlide = styled(Glide)`
    ${ifProp(
        "isOpen",
        css`
            animation: 0.8s ${slideInRightAnimation};
        `,
        css`
            animation: 0.9s ${fadeOutLeftAnimation} forwards;
        `
    )}
```

Comment: I am facing same issue with `const animationStyles = {
  animation: css`
    ${fadeIn} 0.5s
  `,
};` . Can you please me to resolve this?